# Statistic test to prove if there is a difference between A and B from answers A>B, A<B and A=B

Tags: hypothesis-testing, chi-squared-test, binomial-distribution

The conducted test allow participants to respond with the following three answers:
- a) A is better than B (A > B)
- b) B is better than A (A < B)
- c) A is equal to B (A = B)
The first approach I have taken is to run a binomial test only using the information a) and b), proving the null hypothesis

*Ho: There is no statistically significant difference between A and B*

Still, considering this two scenarios:
**a)** 10 answers A=B, 30 answers A>B, 80 answers B>A
**b)** 300 answers A=B, 30 answers A>B, 80 answers B>A

Doing the binomial test between A>B and B>A (not counting A=B) obviously yields the same result for both scenarios. Still, it feels like this difference is more **relevant** in scenario **a**. Is there a way to test for this?.

I have also though of running two binomials (comparing first A=B to A>B+B>A) and, in case this one is significant, comparing A>B to B>A) but I'm not sure if I commit any errors or loss of statistical significance this way OR testing with a Chi Squared GOF and applying post hoc testing in case it is significant, but there is not much info on post hoc tests for GOF.

Comment: Why not test $A \ge B$ and $B \ge A$ instead?

Comment: Wouldn't testing for A >= B or viceversa be too conservative? edit: Sorry I can't seem to write the bigger-equal symbol.

Comment: use the \ge or \le instructions in math mode (between \$ signs) to make $\ge$ and $\le$

Comment: Use McNemar's test. Maybe  it is your binomial test. The number of participants with A=B does not provide any information. If you want to understand why A=B is useless, you can check the process of development of McNemar's test.

Comment: That is what I am trying to understand, how to make sense of the A=B participants. Just to give an example, if I were to put the A product on the market and wanted to compare it with B, I could conduct a research test in which I ask participants if A=B, A<B or A>B. In a case of n(A=B)=5, n(A>B)=30 and n(B<A)=5 I would be optimistic about product A. Instead, if the results were n(A=B)=500, n(A>B)=30 and n(B>A)=5, not as much. I understand I am trying to do two things at once (relevance+preference) so maybe two different tests should be carried out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An intuitive way of treating this would be to assume that, if the participants answer $A=B$, they are as likely to think $A > B$ as to think $B > A$. Then, you could stick with your single binomial test with 2 subsets instead of 3:

- $card(A \ge B) \sim card(A>B) + 0.5 \cdot card(A=B)$
- $card(A \le B) \sim card(A<B) + 0.5 \cdot card(A=B)$

This would yield quite different results from one scenario to the other.